# Plotting Frequency of Vowels in a Paragraph

Tags: python

I wanted to play around with the following idea:

> Give a paragraph, I wanted to find out the relative frequency of usage
>   of each of the five vowels. I wanted to plot a pie chart depicting
>   this.

Here is my code:

```
from sys import stdin
from re import sub
import pylab
DataToRead = stdin.read()
VowelData = sub(r"[^aeiou]","",DataToRead) #Take Out Everything which is NOT a vowel
VowelList = ['a','e','i','o','u']
VowelCount = [sum(map(lambda x: x==Vowel,VowelData)) for Vowel in VowelList] # Number of times each vowel appears
print VowelCount
VowelPerc = [x*100.0/sum(VowelCount) for x in VowelCount] #Find the percentage of each
pylab.pie(VowelPerc,None,VowelList,autopct='%1.1f%%')
pylab.show()
```

It does what it needs to (I think) but I feel there is a better way of doing this (algorithmically speaking). I like Functional Programming so I threw in the Mapper but there is no other reason for that.

Comment: Note that with the `autopct` option, the chart computes percentages automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly advise against `CamelCase` for your variable names – consider `snake_case` instead. Why? Because consistency with existing Python code.

I also suggest better spacing around your operators, e.g. `x == vowel` instead of `x==Vowel` and `pylab.pie(vowel_perc, None, vowel_list, autopct='%1.1f%%')` instead of `pylab.pie(VowelPerc,None,VowelList,autopct='%1.1f%%')`. In general, consistent, even spacing makes code easier to read.

Do not use `map`, or more precisely: do not use `lambda`s. Python has list comprehensions which are exactly as powerful as `map` and `filter`, but are considered to be more readable. Here, your line

```
VowelCount = [sum(map(lambda x: x==Vowel,VowelData)) for Vowel in VowelList]
```

would become

```
count = [sum([x for x in vowel_data if x == vowel]) for vowel in vowel_list]
```

Of course, that is far from optimal as we make five passes through the data. If we use a dictionary, we can reduce this to a single pass:

```
vowels = "aeiou"
counts = dict([(vowel, 0) for vowel in vowels])
for x in data:
    counts[x] += 1
percentages = [counts[vowel] * 100.0 / len(data) for vowel in vowels]
```

Note that I got rid of the unnecessary `vowel_` prefix here, and that I replaced `sum(VowelCount)` with the likely cheaper `len(data)` (but with all “optimizations”, the improvement should be benchmarked, not guessed).

As per the [*pie*-plot documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie), you should consider setting the aspect ratio of your axes, so that the resulting chart doesn't look distorted.

Comment: Even simpler is to use `counts = collections.Counter(data)`

Comment: You could also use `defaultdict` for a more concise code. (Also, you might like to know that Python has a syntax similar to list comprehension for dicts and sets so that you do not need to go through list definition).

Comment: I am realizing more and more that Hashmaps and Dictionaries are magical data structures.

Answer (score 4):

amon's comment about the names of your variable and the way you format your code is quite interesting. If you want more details, [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a style guide for Python code. It is definitely worth a read if you want to write code considered pythonic. You can find automated tools to check that your code respects the guideline such as [pep8online](http://pep8online.com/).

---

Another thing that could be easily improved is the fact that the same thing is (implicitely) defined twice, violating the good old [**Don't repeat yourself**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Indeed, you define the set of vowels in `VowelData = sub(r"[^aeiou]","",DataToRead)` and in `VowelList = ['a','e','i','o','u']`. Probably one of them could be enough. You might think that it's not such a big deal because no one will want to change the definition of vowel but [Y should it be so easy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y#Vowel).

---

[**Keep it simple**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) : if you were trying to count vowels manually in a very very long string, here's what you would do (or at least what you should do) : go through the string one character at a time, if it is a vowel, increment a corresponding counter (one counter per vowel). On the other hand, here's what you wouldn't do : use regexps to remove unwanted characters, then go through the remaining characters to count `a` then go through it again to count `e`, etc. What I am trying to say here is that first you only need to go through the string once, secondly regex is a powerful tool but the overhead in performance and readibility make it a bad option for your use case.

---

**Using the right tool** : at the moment, you are using Lists for `VowelList` and `VowelCount`. Lists are fine but in your case, you have better things :

- for `VowelList`, you should probably use it to know whether a character is to be considerer or not. Thus, the operation you'll care about is to test if a given element is part of a collection. The best data type for that is the [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) : `vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}`. On top of being more efficient (which might or might not be the case for such q small collection), it shows what you have in mind to anyone reading your code.
- for `VowelCount`, it is a bit awkward to have a list of numbers and to have to go through another list to see what they mean. If you want to data (a count) associated to another data (a letter), a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) is usually a good idea. Also for what you are trying to do, Python has some specialised types : [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would allow you not to test if the value is here before incrementing it and even better for you : [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does exactly what you want : `c = Counter(c for c in data if c in vowels}`

---

Finally :

```
from collections import Counter
data="jfalksfhjsdfhljasdhflsdjfhduiysasdvcsdpleaazioqhayiqahbcshjscsd"
vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
count = Counter(c for c in data if c in vowels}
coef = 100./sum(count.itervalues()) # assuming a wovel is found - also use itervalues for Python < 3
prop = {x:coef*y for x,y in count.iteritems()} # or make this a list if you really want it
```

looks pretty good to me and I hope you'll like it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Josay's suggestion to use `Counter`.  I have just two tiny suggestions to add:

- Uppercase letters are vowels too.  You stripped them out with your regex.  I think that mapping them to lowercase would be more reasonable.
- Instead of using a list or a set for the vowels, consider using a string:

  ```
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  ```

  You don't need to do any fancy set operations on `vowels`.  All you need is to be able to iterate over its elements, and strings are iterable.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import lower
from sys import stdin
import pylab

vowels = 'aeiou'
vowel_count = Counter(c for c in lower(stdin.read()) if c in vowels)
print vowel_count

total = sum(vowel_count.itervalues())
vowel_perc = [100.0 * vowel_count[x] / total for x in vowels]

pylab.pie(vowel_perc, labels=vowels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
pylab.show()
```